# Limit of a sequence of function

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the limit of the following sequence of functions defined by $f_n(x) = \frac {[nx]}{n}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

At integers it goes to identity function, so my guess is this sequence converges to identity function. but I don't know how to see, actually it is.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you are using ceiling or floor, but the idea is the same.

$nx-1 < \lfloor nx \rfloor \le nx$, divide across by $n$ to get
$x - {1 \over n} < {\lfloor nx \rfloor \over n} \le x$, and so
$|x-{\lfloor nx \rfloor \over n} | \le {1 \over n}$. Hence
$f_n$ converges to the identity uniformly.

Comment: I am using intergral part of x (floor part of x) only, so I want to accept your answer. but I cant accept the answer before ten mins :(

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.